# If you drink nothing but holy water, are your bodily fluids holy?

Tags: vampire

Are there any stories (movies, books, games, etc)  that address the specific case of drinking holy water as a means to make your bodily fluids (which are mostly made of water) poisonous to vampires, and demons, and the like? I'm not looking for a list, just one or more examples more of what would happen in a specific universe.

Or does the water become no longer holy once consumed?

Comment: Do you have a specific series in mind, or are looking for real-life mythology, or something?  'Cause otherwise the answer could be different in every continuity with vampires...

Comment: Ideally, the Supernatural universe, but any series/universe that even discusses this concept. I found none in my research.

Comment: I distinctly remember **Buffy** using this in an early season (2?), when she was bereft of her powers (some test the Watchers were administering).  She drank a flask of Holy Water, making the vampire who bit her 'poisoned', so she could defeat him easier.

Comment: @Xzero that is exactly what I was looking for. Can you post as An answer?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, you misremember. In that episode ("Helpless", S3E12, Buffy left a glass of holy water for the vampire to drink directly (he was washing down his antipsychotic meds).

Comment: @RussellBorogove - Ah, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

No. Any number of things can defile it such that it is no longer "holy", and while the Catholic Church has not said anything specific about it, slobbering it out of your mouth or leaking it out of other orifices definitely does so. Other churches will have similar rules. Since Supernatural makes an attempt to follow the rules of real mythology, I expect that they do the same for the purely religious. Other shows are not so studious... Constantine (film) has it being sprayed out of fire suppression sprinklers, for instance.

Comment: About the sprinklers, so does supernatural at some point. I can't recall the episode though.

Comment: With regards to (just) Supernatural, "Bobby reveals Sam's possession by Meg by getting him to drink beer laced with holy water." (from [here](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Holy_Water)).  Not a direct refutation, though, since the situation isn't the same.

Comment: Yeh, but that doesn't make his body fluids "holy". It's just using holy water to burn his esophagus.

Comment: But I think mixing it with BEER would count as sufficiently "defiling" it.

Comment: Yawus, you may be correct on that. It's not an easy thing to research though, the church doesn't put up a faq for those who watch silly tv shows.

Comment: @Yawus A lot of Christian rituals use wine, so just mixing with beer isn't *obviously* defiling it.

Answer (score 3):

In her *Infernal Devices* series (specifically **Clockwork Prince**), author Cassandra Clare shows a scene where the heroine walks in on a Shadowhunter drinking large quantities of holy water.  When asked why he is doing this, he explains that he was in a fight with a vampire and was bitten by the vamp.  He says he will wind up drinking gallons of holy water to essentially kill off the vampire infection before it can turn him.  It stuck with me because it was an idea I'd never read before.  Perhaps it wouldn't work on a human, but maybe it works on the Nephilim because he's part angel anyway.

Comment: In one of the early novels, Anita Blake poured holy water on a vampire bite to cleanse it. Doing so was extremely painful but eliminated any ties to the vampire that bit her.

Comment: Something similar works in nethack (the game).  A werewolf bite can infect you (the player) so you become a werewolf and tranform to a wolf every once in a while.  Drinking holy water cures this condition so you're no longer a werewolf.